# parsing a customized plain text file

Tags: bash, unix

I need to parse a file that has the following formatted data and get the 
DIRNAME for the OTHER node.

```
    CLASS=
     (SOURCE=
        (TYPE=FILE)
        (DEFAULT=
           (DIRNAME=${HOME}/information/logs)
        )
      )


    OTHER=
     (SOURCE=
        (TYPE=FILE)
        (DEFAULT=
           (DIRNAME=${HOME}/site/location)
        )
      )

    STUDENT=
     (SOURCE=
        (TYPE=FILE)
        (DEFAULT=
           (DIRNAME=/opt/students)
        )
      )
```

I have to capture everything that is contained in the OTHER= field, like 
so:

```
    OTHER= <whitespace> ( <to capture> )
```

and then I have to capture everything that is within the DIRNAME in the 
OTHER= field, like so:

```
    (DIRNAME=<to capture>)
```

I would like to do this in a sort of robust script that can run in most 
unix systems, anyone know what command line tools I should use for this 
and what sort of regular expressions would I need to capture the data in 
the way I have outlined.

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: weehoo. Lisp meets Oracle tnsnames. Best of breed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the test below:

```
kent$  cat t
    CLASS=
     (SOURCE=
        (TYPE=FILE)
        (DEFAULT=
           (DIRNAME=${HOME}/information/logs)
        )
      )


    OTHER=
     (SOURCE=
        (TYPE=FILE)
        (DEFAULT=
           (DIRNAME=${HOME}/site/location)
        )
      )

    STUDENT=
     (SOURCE=
        (TYPE=FILE)
        (DEFAULT=
           (DIRNAME=/opt/students)
        )
      )

kent$  awk -F= '$1~/OTHER/{i++;print $2} $1~/DIRNAME/ && i{i=0;gsub(/\)$/,"",$2); print $2}' t

${HOME}/site/location
```

note that there was an empty line above output line  ${HOME}/site/location, 
it was the whitespace after `OTHER=`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -ne '/OTHER/,/DIRNAME/{s/^[^D]*DIRNAME=\(.*\))/\1/p}' input_file
${HOME}/site/location
```